# usage of '?' in grep

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep

So, I was playing around with grep and here's the situation :-

I got two files in my root directory, "sample" and "simple", from what I read the `?` regexp matches the occurrence of the preceding character, so the following should give me "simple" as output :-

```
ls | grep 'sia?mple'
```

but it does not seem to work. The following works though :-

```
ls | awk '/sia?mple/ {print}'
```

also ls's version of `?`,`*`,etc seems to work differently than grep or awk

Comment: `ls | grep 's[ia]mple'` will return lines with `simple` or `sample`

Comment: [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) != [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))

Comment: it sure does, @WiktorStribiżew, but why doesn't the '?' work ?

Comment: `sia?mple` matches simple or siample. The `?` only affects the preceding element

Comment: Yes, @LưuVĩnhPhúc, I should have gotten simple as result then but i didn't

Comment: `grep -E 'sia?mple'` will match `simple` or `siample`. The `?` in BRE POSIX (as in your attempt since you used no option with `grep`) matches a literal `?` char. Your example will match `sia?mple` literal string, see [**this demo**](https://ideone.com/CtxADW). In POSIX ERE (enabled with the `-E` option), `?` is a quantifier matching 1 or 0 occurreces of the quantified atom.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew !

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Sorry, didn't knew about that will keep that in mind

Comment: note that [`ls` output shouldn't be parsed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you want to list a file named `simple` then that's just `ls simple`. If you tell us what you're trying to do we can help.

Comment: @EdMorton, Thanks, I was just playing around with grep. And found it strange that ls | grep 'sia?mple', didn't work. The answer provided by melpomene below gave me a satisfactory explanation. Thanks for caring ! Kind sir !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls` does not support `?`, `*`, or any metacharacters at all.

The shell will expand `?`, `*`, `[` `]`, `{` `}` (and a couple of other things) on the command line (if left unquoted). This happens before the command even runs (you can check with `echo s?mple` or `echo s[ai]mple`).

There are many different regex "flavors". Basically, every tool and library has its own regex syntax and quirks.

As for `grep`, check out [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Regular-Expressions).

In [particular](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Basic-vs-Extended):

> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ‘?’, ‘+’, ‘{’, ‘|’, ‘(’, and ‘)’ lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions ‘\?’, ‘\+’, ‘\{’, ‘\|’, ‘\(’, and ‘\)’.

("Basic" regexes is what you get if you run `grep` with default options.)

Thus:

```
grep 'sia\?mple'
```

will match `siample` and `simple`.

Comment: Thanks, kind sir, /? did work, alternatively i found, by using -E I can use the normal '?' regexp

Comment: Right, `grep -E` activates "extended" regex syntax, which is closer to the Perl style syntax people have come to expect nowadays.

Comment: @EdMorton No, the difference OP is seeing is the difference between regexes in `awk` and regexes in `grep` (without `-E`).